# How to check the differentiability of the following function?

Tags: derivatives, entire-functions

For an odd integer $k \geq 1$, let $F$ be the set of all entire functions $f$ such that $$f(x)= |x^k|$$ for all $x \in (-1,1)$. Then the cardinality of $F$ is

1. $0$
2. $1$
3. $> 1$ but finite
4. Infinite.

I think for all integers $k \geq 3$, $f$ is entire. But the answer given is $0$.

Comment: I don't see how the answer can be $0$ if the function $f(z)=z^k$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ is itself an entire function.

Comment: Sorry, i have made the change.

Comment: if $k=1$ the answer is clearly zero, but I dont see why it must holds for odd $k$ greater than $1$.

Comment: I have also checked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function $f$ is an entire function which respects your hypothesis, it coincides with the function $g(z)=z^k$ on the set $(0,1)$ which is itself an entire function.

The set $(0,1)$ has at least one limit point, so by the analytic continuation principle, $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

However, the function $f$ is even when restricted to $(-1,1)$, and $g$ is an odd function if $k$ is odd.

The only function which is even and odd is the constant function which returns zero. This means that the function $f$ is not analytic.